# How to use TooN on Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to use TooN library in Visual Studio 2013.The instruction on the official website says that

> On a unix system, ./configure && make install will install TooN to the correct place. Note there is no code to be compiled, but the configure script performs some basic checks.
>   On non-unix systems, e.g. Windows and embedded systems, you may wish to configure the library manually. See Manual configuration.

But the further instruction is unclear like this ：

> TOON_TYPEOF_DECLTYPE
>   Use the C++11 decltype operator.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you try  https://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/toon/html-user/index.html#sWindowsErrors or read a little more of the manual configuration where it says `Under Win32, the builtin typeof needs to be used. Comment out all the TOON_TYPEOF_ defines to use it.`

Comment: Yes,but mine haven't reached this step...say , should I directly put these header files under the include directory?